# Can't see an UILabel in UIView, it's behind an other label

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, uilabel, xcode-storyboard

I just added a `UILabel` named `label1` to my `UIView` in Interface Builder and I want to put it behind an other `UILabel` named `label2`.

But `label2` is behind `label1` and I dont know how to change the order.

What I want is that if `label2` is hidden, `label1` would be visible behind it.

Comment: do you use storyboard or nib?

Comment: I use main.storyboard ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to add a view below another in Swift:

```
insertSubview(label1, belowSubview: label2)
```

How to change view stacking in Interface Builder (main.storyboard):

Just drag your label1 view above label2 in the document outline (left panel on IB)
[image: changing stacking order]

If your document outline is not open, click this button when you're in the Interface Builder[image: Interface Builder Document Outline button]

The stacking order of your elements is read from the top down, unlike photoshop or similar programs, where the bottom of the list is the bottom layer. In the document outline, you can think of it like a reverse order. The items at the top of the list are at the bottom of the displayed views.

Comment: Yes I know its like Photoshop and other software that uses layers but I had the document outline closed and didn't think about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of ways to change a label position. The following code should work:

```
label = CGRectMake(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height);
```